# How does the agranulocitosis risk of metamizole compare with that of metoclopramide?

Tags: side-effects, risks

I see that metamizole is banned in many countries but not metoclopramide. Are the risks significantly different? I see metoclopramide figures of about 1/100k to 1/1M, but can't find anything for metoclopramide.

Comment: Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and the reasons mentioned in [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.